# how to iterate all img tags and add dynamic domain for those src and return whole string in jquery?

Tags: html, image, jquery-ui, jquery

I have all html tags string like  below

```
var description = "<div class="header"> <div class="logo"> <a href="http://domain.com"> <img src="devimg/logo.png" class="showHome" alt="ssfdf" height="80px" /> </a> </div><div><img class="img1" src="devimg/sss.png"></img></div><div><img class="img2" src="devimg/.png"></img></div> </div>"
```

I have html string like above ,want to iterate all img tags and append some domain to src url
like `<img class="img1" src="www.otherdomain.com/devimg/sss.png">` like this want add domain for every img tag. After replacing all want get whole html tags again with newly appended domain for img tags.

How can I do this one in jQuery?

Comment: Hey @rajesh, your string is not showing.

Comment: I added quote-marks (`"`) to wrap your string of HTML (assuming that the omission of quote-marks was a typo). If those quote marks are missing in your actual code that's a fairly major syntax error that you need to correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code has satisfied my requirment.
data is html string.

```
var temp = document.createElement('div');
    data = data.replace(/src=/gi, "tempsrc=");
    temp.innerHTML = data;
    $(temp).find( 'img' ).each(function() {
    var oldSrc = $(this).attr("tempsrc");
     $(this).removeAttr("tempsrc");
        if(oldSrc){
          $(this).attr("src", "clouddomain.com/"+oldSrc);
        }
    });
```

If you append any html content to dom element it loads the resources like images from ur domain by taking as  relative path.
In the above code replacing some temporary attribute then appending to the one dom element.
then replacing the cloud url.

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gfdB/)

You have to iterate through every img tag, get src and then change src on your img tag.

```
  var otherDomain='www.otherdomain.com';
$('img').each(function(){

    $(this).attr('src', otherDomain + '/' + $(this).attr('src'));

});
```

edit: someone was faster..

I think that Guy already posted solution with replacing string with new domain in src attribute.
You can use regex or replace src attribute in img tag like this:

```
var otherDomain = 'www.otherdomain.com';

description = description.replace('src="', 'src="' + otherDomain);
```

[jsfiddle  - replace string](http://jsfiddle.net/LG9fV/)

Is this the answer you were looking for?

Comment: Hi Tidla, I want iterate the string which contains all html tags including img tags. After replacing all domains for img src tag want to get like string only

Answer (score 0):

If this actually part of the DOM and not a string with jQuery you can run an each on all the img tags and change the src attribute something like this

```
$('img').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://otherdomain.com' + $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zVgpV/

If it's a string you'd have to regex it, your Regex will be something like this

`str.replace(/src="(.*)"/, 'src="http://otherdomain.com/$1"')`

Comment: HI Guy , Is there other jquery functions to find all img tags in string and replace src with new doman?